# How can I instantiate a class with custom names?

Tags: python, class

```
class Zone:
    def __init__(self, price):
        self.price = price

    def __str__(self):
        return f"name is {self.name} and price is {self.price}"

for i in range(1,4):
        new_name=f"zone{i}"
        new_name=Zone(100*i)
        print(new_name.price)
```

Error occured that 'str' object has no attribute price

I want to instatiate a class with custom names. I tried below solution but still not worked:

```
for i in range(1,4):
    new_name=f"zone{i}"
    new_zone=Zone(100*i)
    new_zone.name=new_name
    print(new_name.price)
```

Comment: You just have a typo in your second snippet. You meant the last line to be: `print(new_zone.price, new_zone.name)` *or* `print(new_zone)`.

Comment: if you want to instantiate the class with custom names for each instance why don't you put the `name` as an arg to `__init__` ?

Comment: you get the error because when you wrote `print(new_name.price)` you meant `print(new_zone.price)` (`new_name` is a string, hence _"'str' object has no attribute price"_)

Comment: Do you want to construct variable names like "zone1" and "zone2"? Don't do that. Use a suitable data structure like a list or a dictionary. It makes no sense to recreate their functionality with your own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just meant to have an additional attribute passed to the `__init__()` method:

```py
class Zone:
    def __init__(self, price, name):
        self.price = price
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return f"name is {self.name} and price is {self.price}"

for i in range(1,4):
    new_zone = Zone(100*i, f"zone{i}")
    print(new_zone)
```

Output:

```
name is zone1 and price is 100
name is zone2 and price is 200
name is zone3 and price is 300
```